# Override a module's local.tf variable in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I want to override the value of root_volume_type to gp2 in https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/local.tf

This is the only file I created called main.tf in my terraform code. I want to override this in the code and not set it via the command line while running terraform apply

```
module "eks_example_basic" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//examples/basic"
  version = "14.0.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: You mean that you want to set `workers_group_defaults` with non-default values?

Comment: Yes. But I tried doing it in a variety of ways, and it doesn't work. Can you suggest a proper way?

Comment: Can you show what did you try along with error messages?

Comment: As per this page https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest?tab=inputs I tried doing this module 

"eks_example_basic" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//examples/basic"
  version = "14.0.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  workers_group_defaults = {
    root_volume_type = "gp2"
  }
}

but it throws an error during terraform plan An argument named "workers_group_defaults" is not expected here.

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct because you are **sourcing an example**, which does not support such variables as  `workers_group_defaults`. You can't overwrite it, unless you fork the example and modify it yourself.

`workers_group_defaults` is supported in the **core module**, for instance:

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "default" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}

module "eks_example" { 

  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws" 
  
  version = "14.0.0"  
  cluster_name = "SomeEKSCluster"  
  cluster_version = "1.18"
 
  subnets         = data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids
  vpc_id          = data.aws_vpc.default.id    
      
  workers_group_defaults = { root_volume_type = "gp2" }
}
```